# Using Dagger with Observables, RxJava and retrofit

Tags: retrofit2, rx-java2, dagger-2

### I have a simple code snippet as below:

- I am using Dagger to inject Retrofit to activity
- It is working fine since Dagger is injected at `OnCreate()`
- But If i use a Observable as below to use RxJava, I get a crash since
  retrofit client is not created when observable code is invoked ,
  since injection happens later
- How can I properly use Observable with Dagger

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    Retrofit retrofit;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((ThisForThatApplication)getApplication()).getNetComponent().inject(this);
    }


    Observable<CategoryHomeModel[]> categoriesObservable = retrofit.
            .create(Restapi.class)
            .getCategories1(new GetHeaders().prepareHeaders())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());


}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Turns out, It was very simple ... noting to do with dagger :D

```
private Observable<CategoryHomeModel[]> getCategoriesObservable() {
        Observable<CategoryHomeModel[]> categoriesObservable = retrofit
                .create(Restapi.class)
                .getCategories1(new GetHeaders().prepareHeaders())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        return categoriesObservable;
    }


    private Observable<WalletBalance> getWalletObservable() {
        Observable<WalletBalance> walletObservable = retrofit
                .create(Restapi.class)
                .getWalletBalance1(new GetHeaders().prepareHeaders())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        return walletObservable;
    }

    private Observable<Settings> getSettingsObservable() {
        Observable<Settings> settingsObservable = retrofit
                .create(Restapi.class)
                .getSettings1(new GetHeaders().prepareHeaders())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        return settingsObservable;
    }

    private Observable<SwapSettings> getRatingsObservble() {
        Observable<SwapSettings> ratingsObservable = retrofit
                .create(Restapi.class)
                .rateMySwap1(new GetHeaders().prepareHeaders())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        return ratingsObservable;

    }

    private void executeApis() {
        List<Observable<?>> observables = Lists.newArrayList(getCategoriesObservable(),
                getWalletObservable(), getSettingsObservable(), getRatingsObservble());
        Observable.merge(observables).toList().subscribe(new Consumer<List<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(List<Object> objects) throws Exception {
                Timber.d("");
            }

        }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                Timber.d("");
            }
        });
    }
```